# How is "of " pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, received-pronunciation, weak-forms

I was wondering why we pronounce the word *of* as ä in the phrase "piece of cake" and as *ov* in the phrase "part of life".

What I've tried: After searching on the internet, I've realised that the weak form of the word *of* is *ov* and its strong form is *Of*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133885/discussion-on-question-by-user17162363-how-is-of-pronounced).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike *off*, which is pronounced with an /f/, *of* is pronounced with a /v/. **Never** with an /f/.

But quite often that /v/ gets deleted. For instance, one of the most common things that can come after *of* is the definite article *the*. In fact, I used it in the previous sentence.

In combination, the consonants /v/ and /ð/ don't play well together. No words in English can start with *vth*, and native speakers have trouble pronouncing them together fast. So one of them goes, and it's usually the /v/, leaving the vowel, which is, as usual, an unstressed schwa.

[This happens before other consonants, too](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/448656/15299); it's very common in spoken English to elide unstressed syllables by reducing consonant clusters.

Comment: To succinct, we pronunce 'of' as 'a' rather than 'ov' in the phrases like "piece of cake" and "cup of tea" as these word "piece" and "cup" repsents a quantity in these phrases i.e. "quantity_(unstressed schwa-'a')_cake or tea.                                                                    
                                                                                           So, when ever "of" comes after some quantity (like piece and cup) it becomes an unstressed schwa-'a'. Am I correct or not?

Comment: It's a schwa, not an 'a' or 'o'. English doesn't have a letter for schwa, and neither does the version of Windows I'm currently using, but its IPA symbol is a lowercase 'e' rotated 180 degrees. It's the commonest vowel in English, and it's what happens to unstressed vowels in most words.

Answer (score 0):

For commonly used idioms I do notice some modifications made. "Piece 'a cake" is a good example. "Man 'o the house" also stands in for "man of the house". Both usage cases alter the inflection and attack of the vowels therein. Keep in mind: This all changes in accordance with local color (locational uniqueness). The specifics of one accent or another by region can dramatically effect pronunciation.

Considering my location in South Texas I'll use 'ov (h implied) or uhv (un-emphasized h). Both are readily accepted here due to the prevalence of television being used as primary source for the correction of pronunciation.